# How to concatenate two array objects using jquery without adding duplicates

Tags: jquery

I have two array objects :

```
 var arr1 =[{product_id: 2, name: 'stack'}, {product_id: 3, name: 'overflow'}];

 var  arr2 = [{product_id: 2, name: 'popo'},{product_id: 6, name: 'foo'}];
```

I do jquery like follows:

```
$.each(arr1 , function(){ 
      var productId = this.product_id;
       $.each(arr2 , function(productId){
        if(this.product_id != productId){
           arr2.push(this);
        }
       }); 
   });
```

at the end

arr2 must look like

```
     var  arr2 = [{product_id: 2, name: 'stack'}, {product_id: 3, name: 'overflow'},
             {product_id: 6, name: 'foo'}]
```

am i doing correct jquery coding..?

Comment: does it work? did you test it?....

Answer (score 8):

`$.extend(arr1,arr2)`

This will copy (and overwrite duplicates) from arr2 to arr1.

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Answer (score 8):

```
$.extend(true, arr1, arr2);
```

Extend joins two objects/arrays into the first object.

Comment: The first parameter is used to make sure it does a deep recursion, and checks the values within the array.

Comment: If the attribute is the same in both, it'll be kept.